# How to find element, switch it state, wait network response and check class changed

Tags: javascript, ajax, cypress

I have list of elements on page. By default some of them are disabled and some are enabled. Each element have switch for enabling it. When user switch element to ON position, app send AJAX request, and if response is ok, element changed `data-cy-status` attribute from `off` to `on`.

I want to check it in Cypress test.

```
cy.server();
cy.route('POST', '**/shop/method_payment/').as('methodAdd');

cy.get('[data-cy="payment-method"][data-cy-status="off"]').first().as('methodEl');
cy.get('@methodEl').find('[data-cy="pm-switch"]').click();
cy.wait('@methodAdd');
cy.get('@methodEl').should('have.attr', 'data-cy-status', 'on');
```

But

`cy.get('[data-cy="payment-method"][data-cy-status="off"]').first().as('methodEl');`

save selector in alias, not a DOM element. And when i check it after AJAX response with

`cy.get('@methodEl').should('have.attr', 'data-cy-status', 'on');`

cypress select next disabled element, not enabled one. What is right way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Found solution. Added additional unchangeable selector `data-cy-status-on-init`.

```
cy.server();
cy.route('POST', '**/shop/method_payment/').as('methodAdd');

cy.get('[data-cy="payment-method"][data-cy-status-on-init="off"]').first().as('methodEl');
cy.get('@methodEl').find('[data-cy="pm-switch"]').click();
cy.wait('@methodAdd');
cy.get('@methodEl').should('have.attr', 'data-cy-status', 'on');
```